# No stream value for some songs in Deezer iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, deezer

I'm using the Deezer iOS SDK and almost everything is working well.

However, sometimes, when I request a song (doesn't matter which one), the readable value is 1 but the stream value is 0.

I checked on several devices (iPhone & iPad), with different iOS version (7.0.6 and 7.1.1) and different connectivity (Wifi or 3G).
I though that was because the account used was not a Premium account, but on my iPhone5S it's worked well when my iPad is lost.

I want to know if it's a problem with the account used, the device, the request or whatever it can be to solve it.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this issue (readable=1, stream=0) always happens with the same tracks ? If so can you give the id of the tracks with this issue ? Or does it happens randomly, and the same track can sometime work and sometime not ?

Comment: It happens randomly, and the track sometimes works and sometimes not. That's why I posted this question, it's not the same device or the same song. Really weird.

Since April 10th, Deezer is free on mobile, we don't need a Deezer Premium account to listen music on mobile app. Maybe it's all about that, some of side effect.

Answer (score 1):

The readable property on a track means that you could potentially this track. This readable property depends on a lot of parameters (country, user status...).

One thing is sure though, if you do not have a premium account, you normally cannot have the stream property set.

Hope that helps.

Guillaume.